# Ftp Folder to S3 Transfer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, ftp, boto3

I want to transfer **new** data that appears in my FTP server folder to an S3 folder. I want to run this operation on Lambda or EC2 (10 times a day). We are talking about transferring a maximum of 50Mb whenever this script will run.

The only part I have ready is, the one that figures out what the new data is in the FTP server.

What is a cost effective solution to this task?

Comment: You should also consider [AWS Transfer for SFTP](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/aws-transfer-for-sftp-fully-managed-sftp-for-s3) and the awscli.

Comment: You could simply run a cron job on the FTP server that calls `aws s3 sync <ftp folder> <s3 location>`